# DistanceMatrixService and multiple callback simultaneous

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, callback

Here's the situation :

- We have 1 origin address
- We have x (admit 3) brands which have themselves x (admit 3) stores

I have to determine for each brands, the nearest stores from the origin address.

The problem is the getDistanceMatrix callback function which is asynchronous and they execute on the same time together. I've no idea how to find that such callback correspond to such brands.

So actually, i get all the nearest stores but i don't know how to connect them to their respective brand.

Here's my code :

```
//Origin address
var origin = "origin address";

//For each brands, list store's address
var brand1 = new Array("address1", "address2", "address3");
var brand5 = new Array("address1", "address2", "address3");
var brand29 = new Array("address1", "address2", "address3");

calculateDistance(1, brand1);
calculateDistance(5, brand5);
calculateDistance(29, brand29);

//Classic google code
function calculateDistance(id_brand, adresses){ 
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: adresses,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false,
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
    var tabDistance = new Array();

    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {  
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                var element = results[j];
                var distance = element.distance.value;
                var from = origins[i];
                var to = destinations[j];
                tabDistance[j] = new Array(distance,to);
            }
        }

        //Find the nearest store
        var indice = minDistance(tabDistance);

        alert('Nearest store ' + tabDistance[indice][0]);

    }
}
});
```

Thanks for your help !